# How to do pagination on the same page - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the first container to the second in the same page, like a slide. How do i do that? I tried it with a javascript code that I found but it did not work. I did not find an example of what I want, but I hope you understand. Sorry about my english.

```css
.pagination ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pagination li {
  display: inline;
}

.pagination li a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination li.active a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.pagination li:hover.active a {
  background-color: red;
}

.pagination li:hover:not(.active) a {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 }
    
 a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline overline; 
 color: red;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-FhHowKuM0">
      <p>Unreal Engine 4 - Clock Town South Demo - Pentium G3250 + POV Gtx 660 - 1080p</p><br>
      <img src="Videos/clock town.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"> 
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3ULfZ2EReg">
      <p>Counter Strike Global Offensive - Pentium G3250 + POV Gtx 660 - 1080p</p><br>
      <img src="Videos/Tumbnail cs go.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"> 
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVa9yrHj89g">
      <p>Mad Max - Pentium G3250 + POV Gtx 660 - 1080p</p><br>
      <img src="Videos/Tumbnail mad max.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbw6GahwVi0">
      <p>Fallout 4 - Pentium G3250 + POV Gtx 660 - 1080p</p><br>
      <img src="Videos/Tumbnail fallout 4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>

<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMlv24s4ZbE">
      <p>The Vanishing of Ethan Carter - Pentium G3250 + POV Gtx 660 - 1080p</p><br>
      <img src="Videos/Tumbnail the vanishing of ethan carter.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>

<div class="container text-center" id="paginas">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="">«</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a href="index.html">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos2.html">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos2.html">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if javascript is needed, i just say that i found an example and it didn't work. I want an explanation of how to do, with or without the code.

Answer (score 0):

You mean bootstrap carousel? Here is the usage: [components-carousel](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/), and the [demo](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).

Comment: Let's say I want to display a list of items on the same page but want to paginate it. How is it possible in that way?